# Comparing 2 array lists with 2D boolean array

Tags: java

Im making a blood transfusion  game.I have 2 array lists. One with donors blood type and names and second with recipients blood type and names. All the names I would get user's input and store them in an array (the recipients array list is larger ).

I dont know how to compare the two array lists together using boolean 2D array (should return true or false). For example after all donors and recipients entered their names and blood types the program should tell each if is a match or not.

I know the code below is wrong but I dont know how to do this.

```
 boolean[][] array = new boolean[donorsList]. 
 [recipientsList];
```

Comment: This model wouldn't work because a boolean array can only store true or false. So that would mean you're comparing the arrays by the content of that specific index rather than altogether. It would make more sense to create a separate class which stores names or ids then populate that array based on the matches... Unless you absolutely have to use a boolean array?

Comment: You should start with an example of input and expected output.  Currently it is not clear what you are trying to achieve, and how you are going to achieve it.

Comment: Its not obvious. Why would the structure be a 2D array of boolean? That's not much info. Why not 2 lists with persons, one representing donors, the other recipients, each person some personal info like name and the blood group. Then you could start to find matches?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote up a solution (I'm not a biologist and I don't know how blood type matches work) but in simplistic form it just checks if the exact letters of the blood matches. I'm sure you can modify this yourself. The other thing I did was not use a boolean array rather I used a separate class which contained the two matches, the donor and the participant. Because your current model as I explained in the comments does not make much sense to me. It doesn't make sense to use a boolean array in the case that receivers are more than the donors and you can also have multiple matches of a single donor with multiple receivers..

Main.java

```java
public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Participant donors[] = new Participant[3];
    Participant receivers[] = new Participant[6];
    ParticipantMatch match[] = new ParticipantMatch[6];
    //populate donors
    donors[0] = new Participant("O", "Amy");
    donors[1] = new Participant("A", "Alice");
    donors[2] = new Participant("B", "Ash");
    //populate receivers
    receivers[0] = new Participant("AB", "Joe");
    receivers[1] = new Participant("A", "John");
    receivers[2] = new Participant("O", "Jim");
    receivers[3] = new Participant("B-", "Jace");
    receivers[4] = new Participant("AB-", "Jack");
    receivers[5] = new Participant("A","James");
    //check for match
    int matchcounter = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < donors.length; ++i) {
      for (int j = 0; j < receivers.length; ++j) {
        if (donors[i].matches(receivers[j])) {
          match[matchcounter++] = new ParticipantMatch(donors[i], receivers[j]);
        }
      }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < match.length; ++i) {
      if (match[i] != null) {
        System.out.println(match[i].toString());
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Participant.java

```
public class Participant {
  private String bloodtype;
  private String name;
  public Participant(String bloodtype, String name) {
    this.bloodtype = bloodtype;
    this.name = name;
  }
  public String getbloodtype() {
    return bloodtype;
  }
  public String getname() {
    return name;
  }
  public boolean matches(Participant p) {
    return this.bloodtype.equals(p.bloodtype);
  }
}
```

ParticipantMatch.java

```
public class ParticipantMatch {
  private Participant donor;
  private Participant receiver;
  public ParticipantMatch(Participant donor, Participant receiver) {
    this.donor = donor;
    this.receiver = receiver;
  }
  public Participant getdonor() {
    return donor;
  }
  public Participant receiver() {
    return receiver;
  }
  public String toString() {
    return "Donor: " + donor.getname() + "-Receiver: " + receiver.getname() + "-Bloodtype: " + donor.getbloodtype();
  }
}
```

If we execute that model, we see Amy matches up with Jim while Alice matches up with John and James

```
Donor: Amy-Receiver: Jim-Bloodtype: O
Donor: Alice-Receiver: John-Bloodtype: A
Donor: Alice-Receiver: James-Bloodtype: A
```

As I already mentioned I don't know how blood type matches work so you would need to edit the algorithm that matches them together. I just checked if the actual string matched.